# How to get environment variables defined in serverless.yml in tests

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, jestjs, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework for running lambda functions on AWS.

In my `serverless.yml` there are environment variables that are fetched from SSM.

When I write integration tests for the code, I need the code to have the environment variables and I can't find a good way to do this.

I don't want to duplicate all the variables definitions just for the tests, they are already defined in the serverless.yml. Also, some are secrets and I can't commit them to source conrol, so I would have to also repeat them in the ci environment.

Tried using the `serverless-jest-plugin` but it is not working and not well maintained.

Ideas I had for solutions:

1. Make the tests exec `sls invoke` - this will work but would mean that the code cannot be debugged, I won't know the test coverage, and it will be slow.
2. Parse the `serverless.yml` myself and export the env variables - possible but rewriting the logic of pulling the SSM variables just for tests seems wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution we ended up using is a serverless plugin called [serverless-export-env](https://github.com/arabold/serverless-export-env).

After adding this plugin you can run `serverless export-env` to export all the resolved environment variables to an `.env` file. This resolves ssm parameters correctly and made integration testing much simpler for us.

BTW, to get the environment variables set from the `.env` file use the the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) npm package.

Credit to [grishezz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3834437/grishezz) for finding the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can run node with `--require` option to inject `.env` file to a serverless command.

1. Create `.env` at the project root with `package.json`, and list variables in `.env`.
2. Install serverless and dotenv in the project by `yarn add -D serverless dotenv`.
3. Run a command like `node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/.bin/sls invoke`.

Then, you can get environment variables in the handler `process.env.XXX`.

Comment: My main goal is to get the env variables that serverless knows how to resolve without defining them explicitly. If for example I have a configuration that comes from AWS SSM or an S3 file or something like that, serverless knows how to resolve these. I don't want to explicitly define them again in a .env file

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do mocked unit tests, or something more like integration tests?

In the first case, you don't need real values for the environment variables. Mock your database, or whatever requires environment variables set. This is actually the preferable way because the tests will run super quickly with proper mocks.

If you are actually looking to go with end-to-end/integration kind of approach, then you would do something like `sls invoke`, but from jest using javascript. So, like regular network calls to your deployed api.

Also, I would recommend not to store keys in `serverless.yml`. Try the `secret: ${env:MY_SECRET}` syntax instead (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#referencing-environment-variables), and use environment variables instead. If you have a ci/cd build server, you can store your secrets there.

Comment: Im am looking for a solution for integration tests. Updated the question to clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After searching I did my custom solution

```
import * as data from './secrets.[stage].json'

if( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'){
  process.env = Object.assign( data, process.env );
}
//'data' is the object that has the Serverless environment variables
```

The SLS environment variables in my case at the file `secrets.[stage].json`

Serverless.yml has

```
custom:
 secrets: ${file(secrets.[stage].json)}
```